# Executing some method in class after starting application spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, threadpool

I have a `spring-boot` server app. In one of the function I run some scheduled threads:

```
 private  ScheduledExecutorService pool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
    private threadsNumber = 10;

    @PostConstruct
    void startThreads() {
          for (int i = 1; i <= threadsNumber; ++i){
                pool.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                            //set Thread Local in depends on i
                            // do some other stuff

                        }
                    }
                }, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The question is:
How to in spring-boot avoid annotation `@PostConstruct` and get a result: "execute exactly once after starting app"

Comment: execute your code in the constructor. spring will initiate the bean and you can execute your scheduler

Answer (score 1):

Spring provides the `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` interface and its `onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event)` hook.

For example:

```
public abstract class MyServiceCreationListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
      // do something on container startup
    }
}
```